# How to loop through dataframes objects in environment

Tags: r

I save my dataframes to .RData using different names

```
  save(df1, "df1.RData")
  save(df2,"df2.RData")
  save(df3,"df3.RData")
```

When I read these .RData files in sequence I get these 3 objects in my environment
How can I do select on each of these objects from my environment in a loop.
If I specify a string "df1", "df2" and "df3" it does not work

Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Loop through the names and for each one that is a data frame save it.

```
for(nm in ls(.GlobalEnv)) {
  if (is.data.frame(get(nm, .GlobalEnv))) 
    save(list = nm, file = paste0(nm, ".RData"))
}
```

**1a)** If the above is run in the global environment then it can optionally be shortened to:

```
for(nm in ls()) if (is.data.frame(get(nm))) 
  save(list = nm, file = paste0(nm, ".RData"))
```

**2)** Another approach is to create a named logical vector, `is.df` with one component per object.  Its components are TRUE for data frames and FALSE otherwise so:

```
is.df <- unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))
dfnames <- names(is.df)[is.df]
for(nm in dfnames) save(list = nm, file = paste0(nm, ".RData"))
```

**3)** If there were a distinguishing pattern to the data frame names then we could use that:

```
for(nm in ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = "^df")) 
  save(list = nm, file = paste0(nm, ".RData"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`save` saves the file to disk.  `load("<filename>")` loads the object back into the current environment.  So after `load()` just reference the object by name: `head(df1)` for example.